# How to install Linux Kernel Headers?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, kernel

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.  I'm trying to install third party software that requires the Linux Kernel Headers.  I did so with "apt -y install linux-headers-generic" and there were no error messages.  However, when I try to install the third party software, it complains:

```
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.4.0-210-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-4.4.0-210-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
```

"4.4.0-210-generic" does appear to be the kernel version (that's what "uname -a" shows).  But "apt list" does not show anything with "4.4.0-210" in it.  How can I install the correct headers?

Answer (score 1):

The `linux-headers-generic` will install the `linux-headers-4.15.0-162-generic` as dependency but not the `4.4.0-210-generic`.

Use;

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-4.4.0-210-generic
```

or

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```