How to get WSL2 kernel headers?
How do I get the kernel headers for WSL2 Ubuntu24.04?
Running Windows 10 with WSL2 running Ubuntu24.04, and when I try to build a DKMS linux kernel module, I get the error

$ sudo dkms build eatmydata/0.1
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 cannot be found at /lib/modules/5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2/build or /lib/modules/5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2/source.
Please install the linux-headers-5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 package or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located.

Normally this would be solved with a sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)  , but linux-headers-5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 is not available in apt, my options are:
$ uname -r
5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
$ sudo apt install linux-headers-
Display all 203 possibilities? (y or n)
linux-headers-6.11.0-1002-nvidia            linux-headers-6.8.0-1009-oem                linux-headers-6.8.0-1014-nvidia-lowlatency  linux-headers-6.8.0-1020-nvidia             linux-headers-6.8.0-50-lowlatency
linux-headers-6.11.0-1007-oem               linux-headers-6.8.0-1010-aws                linux-headers-6.8.0-1014-oem                linux-headers-6.8.0-1020-nvidia-lowlatency  linux-headers-6.8.0-51
linux-headers-6.11.0-1008-oem               linux-headers-6.8.0-1010-azure              linux-headers-6.8.0-1014-oracle             linux-headers-6.8.0-1021-aws                linux-headers-6.8.0-51-generic
linux-headers-6.11.0-1009-oem               linux-headers-6.8.0-1010-gcp                linux-headers-6.8.0-1015-aws                linux-headers-6.8.0-31                      linux-headers-aws
linux-headers-6.11.0-1010-oem               linux-headers-6.8.0-1010-gke                linux-headers-6.8.0-1015-azure              linux-headers-6.8.0-31-generic              linux-headers-azure
linux-headers-6.8.0-1001-gkeop              linux-headers-6.8.0-1010-ibm                linux-headers-6.8.0-1015-gcp                linux-headers-6.8.0-31-lowlatency           linux-headers-gcp
linux-headers-6.8.0-1002-gkeop              linux-headers-6.8.0-1010-nvidia             linux-headers-6.8.0-1015-gke                linux-headers-6.8.0-35                      linux-headers-generic
linux-headers-6.8.0-1003-gke                linux-headers-6.8.0-1010-oem                linux-headers-6.8.0-1015-ibm                linux-headers-6.8.0-35-generic              linux-headers-generic-hwe-24.04
linux-headers-6.8.0-1003-gkeop              linux-headers-6.8.0-1010-oracle             linux-headers-6.8.0-1015-nvidia             linux-headers-6.8.0-35-lowlatency           linux-headers-generic-hwe-24.04-edge
linux-headers-6.8.0-1004-gke                linux-headers-6.8.0-1011-aws                linux-headers-6.8.0-1015-nvidia-lowlatency  linux-headers-6.8.0-36                      linux-headers-gke
linux-headers-6.8.0-1005-gke                linux-headers-6.8.0-1011-gcp                linux-headers-6.8.0-1015-oracle             linux-headers-6.8.0-36-generic              linux-headers-gkeop
linux-headers-6.8.0-1005-ibm                linux-headers-6.8.0-1011-gke                linux-headers-6.8.0-1016-aws                linux-headers-6.8.0-36-lowlatency           linux-headers-gkeop-6.8
linux-headers-6.8.0-1005-intel              linux-headers-6.8.0-1011-ibm                linux-headers-6.8.0-1016-azure              linux-headers-6.8.0-38                      linux-headers-ibm
linux-headers-6.8.0-1005-oem                linux-headers-6.8.0-1011-nvidia             linux-headers-6.8.0-1016-gcp                linux-headers-6.8.0-38-generic              linux-headers-ibm-classic
linux-headers-6.8.0-1005-oracle             linux-headers-6.8.0-1011-nvidia-lowlatency  linux-headers-6.8.0-1016-gke                linux-headers-6.8.0-38-lowlatency           linux-headers-ibm-lts-24.04
linux-headers-6.8.0-1006-gke                linux-headers-6.8.0-1011-oem                linux-headers-6.8.0-1016-ibm                linux-headers-6.8.0-39                      linux-headers-kvm
linux-headers-6.8.0-1006-ibm                linux-headers-6.8.0-1011-oracle             linux-headers-6.8.0-1016-oem                linux-headers-6.8.0-39-generic              linux-headers-lowlatency
linux-headers-6.8.0-1006-intel              linux-headers-6.8.0-1012-aws                linux-headers-6.8.0-1016-oracle             linux-headers-6.8.0-39-lowlatency           linux-headers-lowlatency-hwe-20.04
linux-headers-6.8.0-1006-oem                linux-headers-6.8.0-1012-azure              linux-headers-6.8.0-1017-aws                linux-headers-6.8.0-40                      linux-headers-lowlatency-hwe-20.04-edge
linux-headers-6.8.0-1006-oracle             linux-headers-6.8.0-1012-gcp                linux-headers-6.8.0-1017-azure              linux-headers-6.8.0-40-generic              linux-headers-lowlatency-hwe-22.04
linux-headers-6.8.0-1007-azure              linux-headers-6.8.0-1012-gke                linux-headers-6.8.0-1017-gcp                linux-headers-6.8.0-40-lowlatency           linux-headers-lowlatency-hwe-22.04-edge
linux-headers-6.8.0-1007-gcp                linux-headers-6.8.0-1012-ibm                linux-headers-6.8.0-1017-ibm                linux-headers-6.8.0-41                      linux-headers-lowlatency-hwe-24.04
linux-headers-6.8.0-1007-gke                linux-headers-6.8.0-1012-nvidia             linux-headers-6.8.0-1017-nvidia             linux-headers-6.8.0-41-generic              linux-headers-lowlatency-hwe-24.04-edge
linux-headers-6.8.0-1007-ibm                linux-headers-6.8.0-1012-nvidia-lowlatency  linux-headers-6.8.0-1017-nvidia-lowlatency  linux-headers-6.8.0-41-lowlatency           linux-headers-nvidia
linux-headers-6.8.0-1007-nvidia             linux-headers-6.8.0-1012-oem                linux-headers-6.8.0-1017-oem                linux-headers-6.8.0-44                      linux-headers-nvidia-6.11
linux-headers-6.8.0-1007-oem                linux-headers-6.8.0-1012-oracle             linux-headers-6.8.0-1017-oracle             linux-headers-6.8.0-44-generic              linux-headers-nvidia-hwe-24.04-edge
linux-headers-6.8.0-1008-aws                linux-headers-6.8.0-1013-aws                linux-headers-6.8.0-1018-aws                linux-headers-6.8.0-44-lowlatency           linux-headers-nvidia-lowlatency
linux-headers-6.8.0-1008-azure              linux-headers-6.8.0-1013-azure              linux-headers-6.8.0-1018-azure              linux-headers-6.8.0-45                      linux-headers-oem-20.04
linux-headers-6.8.0-1008-gcp                linux-headers-6.8.0-1013-gcp                linux-headers-6.8.0-1018-gcp                linux-headers-6.8.0-45-generic              linux-headers-oem-20.04b
linux-headers-6.8.0-1008-gke                linux-headers-6.8.0-1013-gke                linux-headers-6.8.0-1018-ibm                linux-headers-6.8.0-45-lowlatency           linux-headers-oem-20.04c
linux-headers-6.8.0-1008-ibm                linux-headers-6.8.0-1013-ibm                linux-headers-6.8.0-1018-nvidia             linux-headers-6.8.0-47                      linux-headers-oem-20.04d
linux-headers-6.8.0-1008-nvidia             linux-headers-6.8.0-1013-nvidia             linux-headers-6.8.0-1018-nvidia-lowlatency  linux-headers-6.8.0-47-generic              linux-headers-oem-22.04
linux-headers-6.8.0-1008-oem                linux-headers-6.8.0-1013-nvidia-lowlatency  linux-headers-6.8.0-1018-oem                linux-headers-6.8.0-47-lowlatency           linux-headers-oem-24.04
linux-headers-6.8.0-1008-oracle             linux-headers-6.8.0-1013-oem                linux-headers-6.8.0-1018-oracle             linux-headers-6.8.0-48                      linux-headers-oem-24.04a
linux-headers-6.8.0-1009-aws                linux-headers-6.8.0-1013-oracle             linux-headers-6.8.0-1019-aws                linux-headers-6.8.0-48-generic              linux-headers-oem-24.04b
linux-headers-6.8.0-1009-azure              linux-headers-6.8.0-1014-aws                linux-headers-6.8.0-1019-gcp                linux-headers-6.8.0-48-lowlatency           linux-headers-oracle
linux-headers-6.8.0-1009-gcp                linux-headers-6.8.0-1014-azure              linux-headers-6.8.0-1019-nvidia             linux-headers-6.8.0-49                      linux-headers-virtual
linux-headers-6.8.0-1009-gke                linux-headers-6.8.0-1014-gcp                linux-headers-6.8.0-1019-nvidia-lowlatency  linux-headers-6.8.0-49-generic              linux-headers-virtual-hwe-24.04
linux-headers-6.8.0-1009-ibm                linux-headers-6.8.0-1014-gke                linux-headers-6.8.0-1019-oem                linux-headers-6.8.0-49-lowlatency           linux-headers-virtual-hwe-24.04-edge
linux-headers-6.8.0-1009-nvidia             linux-headers-6.8.0-1014-ibm                linux-headers-6.8.0-1020-aws                linux-headers-6.8.0-50                      
linux-headers-6.8.0-1009-nvidia-lowlatency  linux-headers-6.8.0-1014-nvidia             linux-headers-6.8.0-1020-gcp                linux-headers-6.8.0-50-generic

Thus I am stuck. How do I get the kernel headers?

@close voter, does linux kernel headers/dkms not go under the category "software tools commonly used by programmers" ?

Yes, obtaining Linux kernel headers is NOT a primary programming problem: they are used e.g. for build 3d-party kernel modules. You may type your question in the search engine, and it will show that Ask Ubuntu and Unix&Linux have much more questions on that topic than Stack Overflow has. A general approach is to ask a question on that Stack Exchange site, which has more questions on that topic.

@Tsyvarev I'm not building a 3rd-party kernel module, i am developing my own kernel module. For me, google result #1 is https://askubuntu.com/questions/75709/how-do-i-install-kernel-header-files , and google result #2 is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69918814/how-to-install-linux-kernel-headers

"I'm not building a 3rd-party kernel module, i am developing my own kernel module." - I am installing Linux not for games but for writing programs... but this doesn't make installing Linux as a programming problem, which is suitable for Stack Overflow.

@Tsyvarev a kind of gray-zone i'd say. kernel headers are primarily used by programmers, meaning it qualifies for software tools commonly used by programmers IMO.

@Tsyvarev guess you should vote-to-close this question too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69918814/how-to-install-linux-kernel-headers?noredirect=1&lq=1

Seems to me that the WSL kernel headers are not distributed anywhere, which means you need to compile it yourself:
sudo apt install build-essential flex bc libelf-dev pahole;
git clone 'https://github.com/microsoft/WSL2-Linux-Kernel.git' --single-branch --depth 1 --recurse-submodules;
cd WSL2-Linux-Kernel;
make KCONFIG_CONFIG=Microsoft/config-wsl -j$(nproc);
sudo make modules_install;
sudo make install;
sudo cp /boot/vmlinuz-6.6.36.6-microsoft-standard-WSL2+ /mnt/c/Users/<YourUsername>/vmlinuz-6.6.36.6-microsoft-standard-WSL2+;
printf '[wsl2]\nkernel=C:\\\\Users\\\\<YourUsername>\\\\vmlinuz-6.6.36.6-microsoft-standard-WSL2+\n' | sudo tee --append /mnt/c/Users/<YourUsername>/.wslconfig
sudo reboot now;

ofc 6.6.36.6 and <YourUsername> needs adjusting.

You can download here :
https://kernel.ubuntu.com/mainline/v5.15.133/

and rename/link to 5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2

nope, seems WSL ships modified kernels available at https://github.com/microsoft/WSL2-Linux-Kernel - nice try tho ^^
